# Octave/Matlab implementation of confidence intervals in multiple regression

Tags: statistics, octave, linear-regression

I need to implement the confidence intervals of multiple regression coefficients in Octave/Matlab.

The task is defined in a common manner: data Y, design matrix X, coefficients β so that Y=βX. The code for β is then simply:

```
beta = pinv(X)*Y
```

Now, as a stupid physicist, I am a bit lost in confidence and prediction intervals. Formulas as well as their implementation.

**Note:** I am aware that there is a Matlab function mvregress, but it is still missing from Octave which I am actually using.

**Note 2:** This question was asked at the CrossValidated and marked as off topic cause it focuses on programming.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want to find:

```
[b, bint, r, rint, stats] = regress (y, X, [alpha]).
```

where bint is the confidence interval for beta.

For details, please refer to https://octave.sourceforge.io/statistics/function/regress.html.